# spring cloud stream kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I've built a producer spring cloud stream app and kafka as binder. Here is the application.yml:

```
spring:
cloud:
  stream:
    instanceCount : 1
    bindings:
      output:
        destination: topic-sink
        producer:
           partitionSelectorClass: com.partition.CustomPartition
           partitionCount: 1        
...
```

I have two instances (same app running on a single jvm) as consumers. Here is the application.yml:

```
spring:  
cloud:
  stream:
    bindings:
      input:
        destination: topic-sink
        group: hdfs-sink
        consumer:
          partitioned: true
...
```

My understanding of kafka groups is that messages will be consumed only once, for those consumers in same group. Let's say, if the producer app produces messages A, B and there are two consumer apps in the same group, message A will be read by consumer 1 and messages B, C will be read by consumer 2. However, my consumers are consuming same messages. Are my assumptions wrong?

Comment: The idea with consumer groups is that all consumers within that group will consume all events from a given topic. However, if there are more consumers than partitions for that topic, then N consumers (where N is `#consumers - #partitions`) will be doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, thanks Arek. For 1 partition  and 1 consumer. 
I share the solution for producer\consumer in spring cloud stream app.
Producer:

`spring:
cloud:
  stream:
    instanceCount : 1
    bindings:
      output:
        destination: topic-sink
        producer:
           partitionSelectorClass: com.partition.CustomPartition
           partitionCount: 1`
Consumer:

`spring: 
  cloud:
    stream:
      instanceIndex: 0 #between 0 and instanceCount - 1
      instanceCount: 1
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: topic-sink
          group: hdfs-sink
          consumer:
            partitioned: true

      kafka:
        binder:
          autoAddPartitions: true`